# How to change the background color of a Textblock in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I want a textblock that has blue text on a yellow background.
I can set the blue text with the "Foreground" attribute.
But "Background" doesn't work (that would be too easy I guess).

So what is the best way to do this, wrap it in a Rectangle or Canvas that has a background color?

And, is there anything we should know about Silverlight to understand why they didn't include a Background attribute for many of the elements on which you would often want to set the background color?

e.g. this gives the error "The property Background was not found in type Textblock":

```
<TextBlock 
    Foreground="Blue" 
    Background="Yellow"
        Height="20" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Margin="0"
    Test="this is a test"/>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(VS.95).aspx) is derived from [FrameworkElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement(VS.95).aspx). [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(VS.95).aspx) is derived from [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(VS.95).aspx), which is derived from FrameworkElement. The [Background color property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.background(VS.95).aspx) is placed in Control.

In WPF the [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx) has a [Background Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.background.aspx) of it's own.

The best way to add a color behind your text is to place the text inside a container like a Border or a Grid. Something like:

```
<Grid  Background="Yellow" >  
    <TextBlock Foreground="Blue"
               Height="20"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Margin="0" 
               Text="this is a test"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Using border is usefull in this case.

Comment: what if i need the textblock to take only the needed space , so that the background will only be set to the content size?

Answer (score 10):

For me worked next:

```
<Border Background="GreenYellow">
    <TextBlock Text="sdfs" Height="60" Width="200"  />
</Border>
```

Comment: Some feedback about your answer. Just dumping code is generally not the best thing. You should try to add some explanation what your code does (some text and a link to the official documentation is also a pre). A good answer is the accepted answer on this question ;).

Comment: I agree, you need some feedback however I've been searching around how to do this and this is the best answer

Answer (score 6):

It's not in Silverlight for some reason, although it is in WPF. Just wrap a Border round it (it will resize to the content automatically).

Answer (score 5):

Just if somebody founds this thread googling or binging...

If you need background for that use the label control it's in the toolkit since version 3, and I guess on version 4 it's already included in the core.

Refer [Label Control in Silverlight](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SilverlightLabel12132008105302AM/SilverlightLabel.aspx)