# How to set a background to a textBlock that changes its content

Tags: background, windows-phone-8, textblock

### Background

I'm trying to put a textBlock control at the bottom of the screen (with a small margin below it), and I also wish to set a background for it, so that no matter what is shown behind the textBlock, it will be easy to read.

On Android, you could simply set the background to it, and tell it to have the width and height to be WRAP_CONTENT, so that it will take only the space it needs, but I can't find a similar thing on WP8.

### Current status

This is the xaml I've created:

```
...
<Grid >

    <Image x:Name="fullScreenImage" Stretch="Fill"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />

    <TextBlock   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="0,0,0,200" FontSize="40" x:Name="pictureLabel" TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Foreground="#ff000000" />
</Grid>
```

### The problem

Since the textBlock doesn't have a background property, I had to use something that wraps it. However, since its content changes dynamically, I can't simply set a size for it.

### The question

For now, I would like to simply set its background color.

I would also very appreciate if it would be possible to use a rounded corners rectangle for the background, or a 9-patch image.

How can I achieve setting a background for the textBlock?

Comment: Set the Grid.HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment, VerticalContentAlignment and HorizontalContentAlignment to anything but "Stretch" (Top & Left are good defaults) and the Grid should stop occupying all available space.

Comment: Hi, please don't tag your titles, and please don't reverse edits that are [supported by discussions on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles). The tagging system is perfectly adequate for this purpose, so I've reverted your edit.

Comment: I don't tag the titles . I only put a very relevant important info about which platform the question is about . It's a shorter version of  : "How to do X on Y ? " , yet it's easier to read . It's also easier to read than reading all of the tags AND the title , since the first thing you read is the first word . The most important thing is on which platform I'm asking about. I think it's a very basic thing to have.

Comment: Please add that opinion to that Meta discussion, and see what people think. It is possible you can change the view of the community - especially since that was decided 3.5 years ago. (Btw, don't forget to address people as @name, otherwise they won't be notified - it was just a coincidence that I looked at this page again).

Comment: @halfer , sorry about the "@" , but i don't understand why i need to post about such a basic thing . you can read about this style everywhere and not just here . here , it's even more important as there are many kinds of platforms to ask about . i think that a single word in the title can be targeted at all kinds of people . i don't think that using this style in the title should be taken into such a serious measure . i'm here to help people with development (and myself) . putting a suggestion about how to write would actually limit people and annoy them. i'm very open to how people write.

Comment: It's good that you help people - carry on doing so `:)`. The answer, as I think I've outlined in the past, is that we have a sort of prevailing "house style" here - a quick look shows that _Esoteric Screen Name, Bart, Nikola K., Charles, Goo_ (and probably others) have detagged your titles, fixed your all-lower-case posts, and so forth. Imagine what Wikipedia would look like if everyone wrote their own style guide, then try to think of SO in a similar way. If you disagree with community guidelines, please raise it on meta - that is what it's there for.

Comment: i don't know of community guidelines , and i don't think that when anyone here writes a post the website shows how exactly to write something. it's not an exact science , especially the part of putting the platform name in the title.

Comment: about wikipedia , and in general , i don't consider anything to have high quality based on its look . i think the content matters most , and i think that if wikipedia could have 10 times the content with just a few things that people won't like how they look , it would worth it. wikipedia still doesn't have as much content (especially in hebrew ) as i would want it to have .

Answer (score 3):

The solution is very simple. Just set the HirizontalAlignment to Left. Hope this will work in your case.

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Border Background="#66FFFFFF">                    
                    <TextBlock/>                    
            </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500863/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-textblock-in-silverlight) (which is for Silverlight - but is xaml nonetheless), there is no way to explicitly set a background color for a `TextBlock`. Your best bet is to wrap your `TextBlock` in a `Grid` or `Border`.

If a `Grid` does not work, [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/silverlightnet/thread/e3430563-0a8e-42d6-8256-a19a9a1c68c4/) suggests a `Border` will do the trick:

> A simple border will do, and by not setting its width and height
>   properties, it will shrink/grow based on the size of the TextBlock.

Comment: but when i do this , the grid takes the whole size that it can get , instead of using only the area that the textblock needs.

Comment: Did you try setting your `Grid`'s size equal to that of the `TextBlock`? Then you could let the `TextBlock` take up 100% of the `Grid`.

Comment: Also - see my updated answer for a potential solution which uses `Border`

Comment: i can't set the size of the grid to the one of the textBlock since the textBlock has a size that depends on its content - the more text i put in it , the more width/height it will need to show it.

Comment: Also , the border solution doesn't work , as it uses the max width & height of its container.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the next solution , which works quite fine , but what i really would like to also have is a way to set a min font and max font size , so that if there is a single word , the font might need to be of some size, and if the text is too long , the font will be of a smaller size , all in a dynamic way.

code:

```
label.Text = label;
label.Measure(new Size(RenderSize.Width, RenderSize.Height));
border.Width = label.DesiredSize.Width + border.Padding.Left + border.Padding.Right + border.BorderThickness.Left + border.BorderThickness.Right;
border.Height = label.DesiredSize.Height + border.Padding.Top + border.Padding.Bottom + border.BorderThickness.Bottom + border.BorderThickness.Top;
```

and the xaml:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#ff000000" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="8" Visibility="Collapsed" Padding="5" Background="#bfff0000" Margin="10,0,10,200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="border">
    <StackPanel>
      <TextBlock FontSize="40" x:Name="pictureLabel" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#ff000000" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```